# Update ng-model of input after input's value changed with jquery unsuccessfully

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

*SITUATION*:

This is just an example of what I'm trying to accomplish in a real project, where I get an array of names from a web service, then I locate the inputs with those names, select them and then set their values using jQuery.

*PROBLEM*:

What I need is to know how to update the `ng-model` of those fields which I changed their value attribute using jQuery

I have tried these

1. [Update Angular model after setting input value with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109850/update-angular-model-after-setting-input-value-with-jquery)
2. [Angular model doesn't update when changing input programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777889/angular-model-doesnt-update-when-changing-input-programmatically/37778146)
3. [Update HTML input value changes in angular ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273385/update-html-input-value-changes-in-angular-ng-model)

...but I haven't had luck with any of those options.

I'm using AngularJS v1.4.8 and jQuery v1.11.1

I have tried setting the input type to `hidden` and type `text` with `style: display:none` but I can't get it working properly.

Here is a demo of what I'm trying to do. This has and input and an span bind with the same `ng-model`.

When you click the button, it's supposed to change the input value using jQuery and then update the `ng-model`.

```
<html>

  <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body data-ng-app="app">
    <div data-ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
    <span>Value: {{ctrl.myValue}}</span>
    <input name="myId" type="hidden" data-ng-model="ctrl.myValue" />
    <button data-ng-click="ctrl.changeValue('ValueChanged')">Change Value</button>
    </div>

<script>
//my controller
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function(){

  var vm = this;

  vm.wizard = {
    changeValue: fnChangeValue
  }

  return vm.wizard;

  function fnChangeValue(newValue){
    var e = $('#myId');
    e.val(newValue);
    e.trigger('input'); //first option

    //e.triggerHandler('change'); //second option
  }
});
</script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Actually what are you trying to do?

Comment: Input ng-model: *ctrl.myValue**2***. Span: *ctrl.myValue*.

Comment: @Sajeetharan, thanks for the reply. This is just a demo, but what I'm trying to do is: given a list o names, locate the inputs with those names, set their `value` via jQuery and then update their ng-model. All this is a function called once a get the names from a REST service. Hope I made situation clearer. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: May I ask why you're mixing jQuery and AngularJS? Both frameworks implement a fundamentally different concept and you can achieve what you described with either one.

Comment: I actually tried to use instead the `angular.element` syntax but not luck with that neither :(, really frustrating! I'm open to any suggestion. Maybe I'm missing something trivial here. I've been struggling with this for hours.

Comment: In AngularJS you usually do not work on the DOM, but on the model (JSON) and AngularJS reflects any changes to the DOM automatically. So what your `ctrl.changeValue` should change is not any input element, but the `vm.wizard.myValue`. Your span and input would show the new value instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed ID and added jQuery's `change()` which is probably what you tried to do. Below you can find your code fixed. And here is how this is usually done with AngularJS alone: https://jsfiddle.net/rwtm1uh9/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="app">
  <div data-ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
    <span>Value: {{ctrl.myValue}}</span>
    <input id="myId" data-ng-model="ctrl.myValue" />
    <button data-ng-click="ctrl.changeValue('ValueChanged')">Change Value</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    //my controller
    angular.module('app', [])
      .controller('myCtrl', function() {

        var vm = this;

        vm.wizard = {
          changeValue: fnChangeValue
        }

        return vm.wizard;

        function fnChangeValue(newValue) {
          var e = $('#myId');
          e.val(newValue);
          e.change();
        }
      });
  </script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You write `var e = $('#myId');` and inside your input there is

```
<input name="myId" type="hidden" data-ng-model="ctrl.myValue2" />
```

I think you missed the id attribute try this instead :

```
<input id="myId" type="hidden" data-ng-model="ctrl.myValue2" />
```